# Lean: define product of R-ideal and R-module

Tags: lean

I am trying to learn Lean and I am trying to figure out how one would create a new R-module `I*M = {i*m | i in I, m in M}` from an ideal I and an R-module M.

So my attempt was to define first a map `ideal_mult` that would create a new R-module and then figure out how to assign a nice notation for it.

```
import ring_theory.ideals
import algebra.module

universes u v
variables {R : Type u} {M : Type v}
variables [comm_ring R] [add_comm_group M] [module R M]
variables (I: ideal R)

def ideal_mult (I: ideal R) (M: Type v)
        [add_comm_group M] [module R M]: Type v
        :=
    sorry

#check ideal_mult I M
```

How could I define this, so that I could for example state a hypothesis like `(h: I*M = M)`?

Thank you for the help!

Comment: You should probably ask this at https://leanprover.zulipchat.com/ where `mathlib` development is concentrated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should `import ring_theory.ideal_operations`. It has the definition that you want at https://github.com/leanprover-community/mathlib/blob/master/src/ring_theory/ideal_operations.lean#L556

You can then type `I • ⊤` for the product (`•` = "\bullet", in VScode-lean, also `⊤` = "\top", which is the maximal submodule of `M` i.e., you can think of it as `M` itself). Your hypothesis would become `I • ⊤ = ⊤`.